# Hadoop cluster with Linux as master and windows 7 as slave

Tags: hadoop

I want to set up a hadoop environment with linux fedora as master and windows 7 machine as slave. Is this combination possible and if so, do I need to install cygwin in windows 7?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The good practice says do not run hadoop on the Windows (simple as that ).

Why do you want to do that?
In case you want to test something use pseudo distributed mode (run all hadoop services on one machine)

Additional thing, I would recommend to use some distribution of the hadoop, for instance cloudera.
This link explains step-by-step how to setup it.

https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDH4DOC/CDH4+Installation+Guide
This is pretty simple and what is the important, very briefly documented

Comment: I know that linux is always better than windows as the hadoop scripts are in shell script which can only be run in linux environment. What I want is that possible which such a combination as queried?

Comment: In addition to scripts Hadoop has native libraries that works for Linux only (despite java)